# How to pass folder from master node to worker node?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

How do I pass a complete folder from a master node to a worker node in spark?

I am using one master node and one worker node in a standalone cluster.

`sc.addFile()` passes a file from master to worker, but I want to pass a folder.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: grammar, formatting

Answer (score 0):

There is another method available:

> public void addFile(String path,
>                      boolean recursive)
>
> recursive - if true, a directory can be given in path. Currently directories are only supported for Hadoop-supported filesystems.